# Problem with grid alignment

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

This grid works:

```
Grid[Table[Append[ConstantArray[1, 5],
If[i === 1, Button["", 0;, ImageSize -> {30, 315}], SpanFromAbove]],
{i, 20}], Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> All]
```

I want the first row to be one single place, except for the button, but when I do it, it gets crap:

```
Grid[Table[Append[If[i === 1, Prepend[ConstantArray[SpanFromLeft, 4], 1], ConstantArray[1, 5]],
If[i === 1, Button["", 0;, ImageSize -> {30, 300}], SpanFromAbove]],
{i, 20}], Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> All]
```

What can I do to the second piece of code to make the button align like it did the first time?

Comment: `ImageSize -> {30, Full}` helps a bit but does not solve the problem.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of my own report: [(13349)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13349) -- please take a look and tell me if you disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable for you to combine the grid and the button using Row?

```
In[129]:= Framed[Row[{Grid[Table[ConstantArray[1, 5], {20}], Frame ->All],
Spacer[2],Button["", 0;, ImageSize -> {30, 315}]}], FrameMargins -> 0]
```

This may give you more flexibility in layout options.