# reduce extra space between elements in a cell of a grid

Tags: graphics

We have four disks in a cell which are too far away each other. The `Grid` has been generated by below code as long as `disk` and `style` were defined by

`disk = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{1, 1}, Scaled[{.35, .35}]]}];
style = {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14, Bold, Blue};`

```
Grid[{

{" ", Style["Number", style]},
   {Style["doubleNumber", style],
 Grid[{{disk, disk}, {disk, disk}}]}},
 Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.13], Scaled[.09]}, 1},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

The problem is the distance between disks. We so much tried to close all disks as much as possible but we could not do that. I mean we want to approach disk in a distance that are still recognizable. However we used `ImagePadding` or `Offset` but we could not reach the desired case.
How can we reduce the extra space between disks?

Comment: What about `Scaled[{.35, .35}]`? do you want that 15% margin or not?

Comment: Unfortunately the design of Grid is too complicated. But you can try something like `disk=Graphics[{Green,Disk[{1,1},Scaled[.48]]},PlotRange->All];
style={FontFamily->"Times",FontSize->14,Bold,Blue};
Grid[{{" ",Style["Number",style]},{Style["doubleNumber",style],
di=Grid[{{disk,disk},{disk,disk}},Spacings->{0,0}(*,Dividers\[Rule]All,*)]
}},Frame->All,ItemSize->{{Scaled[.13],Scaled[.37]},1},FrameStyle->Directive[Black,Thick]]`

Comment: This earlier question [Grid - sizing and spacing problems with spanning cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/grid-sizing-and-spacing-problems-with-spanning-cells/13370#13370) might give some ideas to deal with `Grid` challenges.

Comment: Kuba, We just reduce the extra space between disks without increasing size of the cell. The suggestion way by @Rolf, changes the size of the cell. As well as the size of disks are Ok. we are not trying to reduce their size.

Comment: I have used: `dotSizes = {40};
dots = Graphics[{Pink, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> #] & /@ dotSizes;` by help of @Jagra

Comment: However we can use : `GraphicsGrid[ConstantArray[disk, {2, 2}]]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not exactly certain what you want to achieve, but the following might give some ideas to do it:

```
disk = Graphics[{Green, Disk[{1, 1}]}, 
   ImageSize -> 40];
style = {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14, Bold, Blue};

Grid[{
  {" ", Style["Number", style]},
  {Style["doubleNumber", style],

   Grid[{
     {disk, disk},
     {disk, disk}}]
   }
  },
 Frame -> All,   
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]